# Finding $4x^{2}-\frac{9}{x^{2}}$ if $2x-\frac{3}{x}=5$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $2x-\frac{3}{x}=5$, determine the value of $4x^{2}-\frac{9}{x^{2}}$.

I tried to expand the equation, but all I got was $4x^{2}+\frac{9}{x^{2}}=37$. How am I supposed to solve this?

Also, I think I made a mistake writing the equation. This is my first time trying to format mathematics here. If anyone would be so kind to show me the mistakes?

Comment: @J.G. So sorry and thank you for pointing it out! I am still confused with the formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: we can write $2x+3/x=5$ as $2x^2-5x+3=0$. Solve this quadratic and then plug your solutions into the thing that you're trying to find the value of.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible values. Since $0=2x^2-5x-3=(2x+1)(x-3)$, either $x=-\frac{1}{2}$ so that $4x^2-\frac{9}{x^2}=-35$, or $x=3$ so that $4x^2-\frac{9}{x^2}=35$.

Answer (score 1):

You need two numbers $A$ (a stand-in for $2x$) and $B$ (a stand-in for $-\frac{3}{x}$) that add up to $5$. But also $A\cdot B$ needs to equal $-6$, since $2x\cdot-\frac{3}{x}=-6$. The two numbers $A$ and $B$ have to be $6$ and $-1$.

Then you are asking for $A^2-B^2$. It could be that you get $35$ or you get $-35$.